# Java 8 Stream IllegalStateException: Stream has already been operated on or closed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, data-generation

I'm trying to generate Order instances using the Stream API.  I have a factory function that creates the order, and a DoubleStream is used to initialize the amount of the order.

```
private DoubleStream doubleStream = new Random().doubles(50.0, 200.0);

private Order createOrder() {
    return new Order(doubleStream.findFirst().getAsDouble());
}

@Test
public void test() {

   Stream<Order> orderStream = Stream.generate(() -> {
       return createOrder();
   });

   orderStream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);

 ...

}
```

If I initialize the `Order` instance using a literal (1.0), this works fine.  When I use the doubleStream to create a random amount, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is in the javadoc of `Stream` (emphases mine):

> **A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once**. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. **A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused**.

And in your code, you do use the stream twice (once in `createOrder()` and the other usage when you `.limit().forEach()`

Answer (score 4):

As said in other answers, `Stream`s are single-use items and you have to create a new `Stream` each time you need one.

But, after all, this isn’t complicated when you remove all your attempts to store intermediate results. Your entire code can be expressed as:

```
Random r=new Random(); // the only stateful thing to remember

// defining and executing the chain of operations:
r.doubles(50.0, 200.0).mapToObj(Order::new).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or even simpler

```
r.doubles(10, 50.0, 200.0).mapToObj(Order::new).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Wow - That's very elegant - I love it!

Comment: When I try it - Eclipse says: "The constructed object of type Order is incompatible with the descriptor's return type double".  Thoughts?

Comment: I was in a hurry yesterday, hence the oversight, `map` has to be `mapToObj` as it changes the type from primitive type `double` to a reference type, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

[As fge states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990579/438154), you can't (shouldn't) consume a `Stream` more than once.

> Any idea how to fix this?

From the Javadoc of [`Random#doubles(double, double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#doubles-double-double-)

> A pseudorandom double value is generated as if it's the result of
>   calling the following method with the origin and bound:
>
> ```
> double nextDouble(double origin, double bound) {
>     double r = nextDouble();
>     r = r * (bound - origin) + origin;
>     if (r >= bound) // correct for rounding
>        r = Math.nextDown(bound);
>     return r;
> }
> ```

Implement such a method and use it to get a new `double` value each time you need one instead of trying to get it from a `DoubleStream`. Possibly use a `DoubleSupplier`.

```
private final Random random = new Random();
private DoubleSupplier supplier = () -> nextDouble(random, 50.0, 200.0);

private Order createOrder() {

    return new Order(supplier.getAsDouble());
}

private static double nextDouble(Random random, double origin, double bound) {
    double r = random.nextDouble();
    r = r * (bound - origin) + origin;
    if (r >= bound) // correct for rounding
        r = Math.nextDown(bound);
    return r;
}
```

If you're not going to reuse the `nextDouble` method, you can inline the values `50.0` and `200.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - that was very helpful.  I also came up with a different implementation that works well for now:

```
private DoubleStream doubleStream = new Random().doubles(50.0, 200.0);

private List<Order> createOrders(int numberOfOrders) {
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
doubleStream.limit(numberOfOrders).forEach((value) -> {
    Order order = new Order(value);
    orders.add(order);
});
return orders;
}
```

Thanks again!

Ole

Answer (score 0):

Your method could be a one-liner like this instead. You need to use `mapToObj`, not `map`

```
private List<Order> createOrders(int numberOfOrders) {
     return doubleStream.limit(numberOfOrders).mapToObj(Order::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: That's really sweet!  Thanks!

Comment: Hm...When I run createOrders(10) I still get IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated on or closed.

Comment: Never mind - something was wrong in the test.  Great solution!!

Comment: OK - I figured out what the problem was.  If I call createOrders more than once in the same method I get the exception.  Any thoughts on how to get around this?  Thanks again.

Comment: OK - FIgured it out.  A new random has to be created with each call. So:   private List<Order> createOrders(int numberOfOrders) {
      return new Random().doubles(50, 200).limit(numberOfOrders).mapToObj(Order::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }

Answer (score 0):

You should use Supplier function interface for your initialization like this

```
Supplier<Stream<Double>> streamSupplier = () -> (new Random().doubles(50.0, 200.0).boxed());
```

And change your way to get double like this

```
streamSupplier.get().findFirst().get()
```

Then it works normally.

Found this way from the post [Stream has already been operated upon or closed Exception](http://javabycode.com/uncategorized/stream-already-operated-upon-closed-exception-java-8.html)