# Using java 8 streams to generate pairs of integers

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to generate pairs of integers - I have a class Pair with a constructor taking 2 ints. The following code works but seems rather clunky - in particular the conversion from an intStream to an object stream using mapToObj(Integer::new).

```
private static List<Pair> success() {
    return IntStream.range(0, 10).
            mapToObj(Integer::new).flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(12, 15).
                mapToObj(j -> new Pair(i, j))).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Firstly does anyone have a more elegant way to do this ?

Secondly when I refactored to extract some streams as variables, I get an error: IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed. Here is the refactored method - does anyone know if this a problem with the code ?

```
static List<Pair> fail() {
    Stream<Integer> outer = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(Integer::new);
    IntStream inner = IntStream.range(12, 15);
    Stream<Pair> pairStream = outer.flatMap(i -> 
            inner.mapToObj(j -> new Pair(i, j)));
    return pairStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: answer to your second question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990451/java-8-stream-illegalstateexception-stream-has-already-been-operated-on-or-clos

Comment: If you know a little maths you can do `IntStream.range(0, 30).mapToObj(i -> new Pair(i/3, 12 + i%3)).collect(Collectors.toList());`, but I agree with @Jeffrey. Nothing is going to be clearer than nested `for` loops.

Comment: static imports for IntStream.range and Collectors.toList will help reduce the information-sparse bulk.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to make it a bit more concise by replacing `mapToObj(Integer::new)` with `boxed`- but apart from that, Java is not that concise:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .boxed()
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(12, 15)
                               .mapToObj(j -> new Pair(i, j)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As for the second question: There are other answers which link to the problem. The concrete problem is that `inner` is not used once, but each time of the outer `flatMap()`.

This way it works:

```
        final IntStream range = IntStream.range(0, 10);
        List<Pair> ps =  range
               .boxed().flatMap(i -> {
                   final IntStream range1 = IntStream.range(12, 15);
                   return range1.
                           mapToObj(j -> new Pair<>(i, j));
               }).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: static imports for IntStream.range and Collectors.toList will help reduce the bulk.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use plain `for`-loops? Plain `for`-loops will:

1. Look nicer
2. Make your intent clear

```
static List<Pair> fail() {
    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>(30);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 12; j < 15; j++) {
            pairs.add(new Pair(i, j));
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

Comment: What OP needs is actually not zipping, it's cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Pair` class accepts primitive ints you can eliminate the unnecessary boxing this way:

```
private static List<Pair> success() {
    return IntStream.range(0, 10).
            mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(12, 15).
                mapToObj(j -> new Pair(i, j))).
            flatMap(Function.identity()).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As for extracting streams into variables, you may create a supplier instead:

```
private static List<Pair> success() {
    Supplier<IntStream> inner = () -> IntStream.range(12, 15);
    return IntStream.range(0, 10).
            mapToObj(i -> inner.get().
                mapToObj(j -> new Pair(i, j))).
            flatMap(Function.identity()).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Though it seems unnecessary for me to extract the stream into the variable.